# mysql database backup class - help me to add PORT feature

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db backup class but there is no option to adding the PORT feature to save backup from remote db. Currently the script is working fine with default port. Can anyone help me to add the PORT feature within this script?.

```
$host = $_POST['dbhost'];
$user = $_POST['dbuser'];
$password = $_POST['dbpass'];
$databaseName = $_POST['dbname'];
$path = "$savepath"; // Put the complete path here -- /home/user/database.sql for example

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/**
 * Define database parameters here
 */
define("DB_HOST", $host);
define("DB_USER", $user);
define("DB_PASSWORD", $password);
define("DB_NAME", $databaseName);
define("OUTPUT_DIR", $path);
define("TABLES", '*');

/**
 * Instantiate Backup_Database and perform backup
 */
$backupDatabase = new Backup_Database(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$status = $backupDatabase->backupTables(TABLES, OUTPUT_DIR) ? 'OK' : 'KO';
echo "<br /><br /><br />Backup result: ".$status;
header('Location: index.php');
/**
 * The Backup_Database class
 */
class Backup_Database {
    /**
     * Host where database is located
     */
    var $host = "";

    /**
     * Username used to connect to database
     */
    var $username = "";

    /**
     * Password used to connect to database
     */
    var $passwd = "";

    /**
     * Database to backup
     */
    var $dbName = "";

    /**
     * Database charset
     */
    var $charset = '';

    /**
     * Constructor initializes database
     */
    function Backup_Database($host, $username, $passwd, $dbName, $charset = 'utf8')
    {
        $this->host     = $host;      
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->passwd   = $passwd;
        $this->dbName   = $dbName;
        $this->charset  = $charset;

        $this->initializeDatabase();
    }

    protected function initializeDatabase()
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->passwd);
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $conn);
        if (! mysql_set_charset ($this->charset, $conn))
        {
            mysql_query('SET NAMES '.$this->charset);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Backup the whole database or just some tables
     * Use '*' for whole database or 'table1 table2 table3...'
     * @param string $tables
     */
    public function backupTables($tables = '*', $outputDir = '.')
    {
        try
        {
            /**
            * Tables to export
            */
            if($tables == '*')
            {
                $tables = array();
                $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $tables[] = $row[0];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
            }

            $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.$this->dbName.";\n\n";
            $sql .= 'USE '.$this->dbName.";\n\n";

            /**
            * Iterate tables
            */
            foreach($tables as $table)
            {
                echo "Backing up ".$table." table...";

                $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
                $numFields = mysql_num_fields($result);

                $sql .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
                $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
                $sql.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

                for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
                {
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                    {
                        $sql .= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                        for($j=0; $j<$numFields; $j++)
                        {
                            $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                            $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                            if (isset($row[$j]))
                            {
                                $sql .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $sql.= '""';
                            }

                            if ($j < ($numFields-1))
                            {
                                $sql .= ',';
                            }
                        }

                        $sql.= ");\n";
                    }
                }

                $sql.="\n\n\n";

                echo " OK" . "<br />";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return $this->saveFile($sql, $outputDir);
    }

    /**
     * Save SQL to file
     * @param string $sql
     */
    protected function saveFile(&$sql, $outputDir = '.')
    {
        if (!$sql) return false;

        try
        {
            $handle = fopen($outputDir.'/db-backup-'.$this->dbName.'-'.date("Ymd-His", time()).'.sql','w+');
            fwrite($handle, $sql);
            fclose($handle);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find this class, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: i found this class @Micah, can u help?

Comment: Easy. Rewrite your class with mysqli, then use `mysqli::__construct` to connect to your db server. You should do this nevertheless, because the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: Need any more help? The mysqli library behaves pretty similarly so it should be an easy fix.

Comment: @Bjoern thanks for ur comment. can you please edit my code and answer it. I would really appreciate your help. Im unable to edit the code because Im newbie to class..

Comment: @Micah can u please show me how can i add the port here - $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->passwd);
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $conn);

Comment: You would just pass foo.bar:1234 to the construction, and specify the port that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port in the host parameter i.e. foo.bar:1234. [Check this out for the actual documentation](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect). However mysql_connect is deprecated, and will be removed soon. You should take the time and upgrade to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli).